# How to Prevent duplicate record from being saved

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

The following code prevents me from saving a new record. I'd be pleased if someone could edit it for me. Whether the record exists or not, the message "Record exists" is displayed.

Try

```
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(subject_id) Or rbnCore.Checked = False And rdbElective.Checked = False Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(password) Then
            MessageBox.Show("One or more fields have not been left empty.", "Save Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
            txtSubjectCode.Focus()
        Else
            If rbnCore.Checked = True Then
                subject = "Core"
            Else : subject = "Elective"
            End If

            cmd2 = New SqlCommand("select count(*) from ProgramDetails.Subjects where IdNumber = " & txtIDNumber.Text & " ", cn)
            queryResult = cmd2.ExecuteScalar
            If queryResult = 0 Then
                qry = "Insert into ProgramDetails.Subjects(SubjectCode,SubjectName,SubjectType,UserID,Password)values(@SubjectCode,@SubjectName,@SubjectType,@UserID,@Password)"
                cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectCode", txtSubjectCode.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectName", txtSubName.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectType", subject))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserID", txtUserName.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Password", txtPassword.Text))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Record successfully saved", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                btnSave.Enabled = False
                btnClear.Focus()
                showgrid()
            End If
            MessageBox.Show("Record already exists", "Existing record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: ? So you don't want the user to be able to add a new row, ever? There is a very easy way to write that...

Comment: A nice combination of SQL injection and a failure to handle the test and insert atomically.  How much code would you like?

Comment: I want the user to be able to save only new records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
    Dim queryResult As Integer
     Try
        cmd2 = New SqlCommand("select count(*) from ProgramDetails.Subjects where IDNumber = '" & txtIDNumber.Text & "'", cn)
        queryResult = cmd2.ExecuteScalar
        If queryResult = 0 Then
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(subject_id) Or rbnCore.Checked = False And rdbElective.Checked = False Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(password) Then
                MessageBox.Show("One or more fields have not been left empty.", "Save Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
                txtSubjectCode.Focus()
            Else
                If rbnCore.Checked = True Then
                    subject = "Core"
                Else : subject = "Elective"
                End If
                qry = "Insert into ProgramDetails.Subjects(SubjectCode,SubjectName,SubjectType,UserID,Password)values(@SubjectCode,@SubjectName,@SubjectType,@UserID,@Password)"
                cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectCode", txtSubjectCode.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectName", txtSubName.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectType", subject))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserID", txtUserName.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Password", txtPassword.Text))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Record successfully saved", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

                btnClear.Focus()
                showgrid()
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Record already exists.", "Existing Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed out the other half of your conditional if statement.

```
     If queryResult = 0 Then
            qry = "Insert into ProgramDetails.Subjects(SubjectCode,SubjectName,SubjectType,UserID,Password)values(@SubjectCode,@SubjectName,@SubjectType,@UserID,@Password)"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectCode", txtSubjectCode.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectName", txtSubName.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubjectType", subject))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserID", txtUserName.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Password", txtPassword.Text))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Record successfully saved", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            btnSave.Enabled = False
            btnClear.Focus()
            showgrid()
        Else
```

MessageBox.Show("Record already exists", "Existing record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

```
        End If
```

That ought to give you what you want.

Comment: Ooops, messed up the code entry, sorry.  In essese if you look at your original code you will always get the message because it follows the if statement as opposed to being part of it.  If some condition is met do something or Else do something else.

Comment: Please the whole code is what I've posted. Kindly edit it to enable the user to add new record as well as prevent duplicate record from being added.